# Can't get the builder pattern in Twitter Kit to work....Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, twitter, builder, twitter-fabric

I cant get this builder pattern using twitter kit to work for nothing...
what gives...

```
  import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.internal.SearchTimeline;
  import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.internal.TimelineListAdapter;
  import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.internal.TweetViewMetric;
  import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.internal.UserTimeline;

  public class FragTwitterTimeline extends BaseFragment {

public String remoteid;
DeviceInfo dvinfo;
@Inject
PubnubServices pubnubServices;
boolean animationFragmentEnd = false;

ListView lv;
UserTimeline userTimeline;
SearchTimeline searchTimeline;

public static FragTwitterTimeline newInstance(String args1)
{
    FragTwitterTimeline fragTwitterTimeline = new FragTwitterTimeline();

    // arguments
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString("args", args1);
    fragTwitterTimeline.setArguments(arguments);
    return fragTwitterTimeline;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitter_timeline,
            container, false);
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.twitterList);


    final TimelineListAdapter adapter = new TimelineListAdapter(getActivity(),
            userTimeline);

    userTimeline = new UserTimeline.***Builder***().screenName("fabric").build();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
    return view;
}
```

The builder word is RED in android studio. Says, "Says Cannot Resolve Symbol".

Comment: It was because that method is only available in version 1.4.0, I was using an earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have to use version 1.7.0.